# android: is there Intent.Action of font setting changed?

Tags: android, fonts, setting

In android, when some of setting changed, the activity of app must reCreate, which may result in app crashed, like language or font setting; I know language setting's Intent.Action is ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED, but can't find the font setting's Intent.Action; so the question is :
what is font setting's Intent.Action in Android, if not, how to handle the case that font setting changed？

Answer (score 1):

I got it;

android.intent.action.FONT_CONFIG_CHANGED

may be you guys can't find it in the Google source code!
my team custom-fitted the source code!